# FFMPEG amix filter causes main audio stream to cut out

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

So I have a video called 1.mkv and would like to mix in a variety of different audio clips at certain points. To do this I'm using the -filter_complex option. However, I'm running into some problems because when ffmpeg tries to mix in the first audio stream the audio works for a short while when the clip is playing and then all audio cuts out. I'm running ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0(which is up to date with my distro). Another "weird" thing about the video output is that in xplayer the video will freeze after the audio cuts out, and will work if you skip far enough ahead in the video(not sure if this is helpful but it might give some extra clues).

Full command:

```
ffmpeg -i "1.mkv" -i "5.wav" -i "2.wav" -i "3.wav" -i "6.wav" -i "7.wav" -i "4.wav" -i "9.wav" -i "8.wav" -i "10.wav" -filter_complex "[0:0]setdar=4/3[v0];

[2:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=20000|20000,volume=0.5[ad2];

[4:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=900000|900000,volume=0.5[ad4];

[3:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=300000|300000,volume=0.5[ad3];

[1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=720000|720000,volume=0.5[ad1];

[7:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=1140000|1140000,volume=0.5[ad7];

[9:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=1260000|1260000,volume=0.5[ad9];

[8:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=1020000|1020000,volume=0.5[ad8];

[5:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=960000|960000,volume=0.5[ad5];

[6:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=480000|480000,volume=0.5[ad6];
[0:1]volume=1[ad0];
[ad0][ad2][ad4][ad3][ad1][ad7][ad9][ad8][ad5][ad6]amix=inputs=10:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm[a0]" -map "[v0]" -map "[a0]" -c:v libx264 -ar 44100  -c:a libmp3lame -preset ultrafast -crf 17 -b:v 1M out2.flv
```

partial command

```
ffmpeg -i "1.mkv" -i "2.wav" -filter_complex "[0:0]setdar=4/3[v0];
[1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=20000|20000,volume=0.5[ad2];
[0:1]volume=1[ad0];
[ad0][ad2]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm[a0]" -map "[v0]" -map "[a0]" -c:v libx264 -ar 44100  -c:a libmp3lame -preset ultrafast -crf 17 -b:v 1M out2.flv
```

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve this by playing around with the audio filters. The fix was converting the mono stream into a stereo before applying the audio filters. I was considering deleting the question but I'll leave it up incase someone has the same problem in the future.

mono to stereo

```
[1][1]amerge=inputs=2[a1]
```

Comment: You're already doing this with `[1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo`. You're using a very old version. Latest is 4.1. Upgrade and try your original command.